# How do I convert real gdp into chained-dollar real GDP?

Tags: econometrics, gdp

I have quarterly data for real GDP from 1981-2015. I also have quarterly chained-dollar real GDP from 61-2012. I need to have them converted into one series.

I've looked up several different formulas but most of them require a price index. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't access a price index? I'm not sure it is possible without a price index.

Comment: My professor has told me I don't need one. As far as I can tell I need the average growth rate and the real gdp. I'm just unsure on how to proceed from there.

Comment: If you have real GDP and nominal GDP, you can divide nominal by real to get a price index known as the GDP deflator.

Comment: The two series I have to use are:

Canada; Chained (2002) dollars (Dollars); Seasonally adjusted at annual rates; Gross domestic product (GDP) at market prices *Terminated*and
Canada; Seasonally adjusted at annual rates; Gross domestic product at market prices